# Can DMSA be used in pacients with amalgam fillings?

Tags: toxicology

Let's say a patient is suffering of chronic heavy metal poisoning by occupational exposure to mercury salts (HgCl2).

Is it safe for this patient to undergo a DMSA detox protocol given the fact that he has a few amalgam dental fillings. What if the removal of the fillings is not an option at that particular moment, but chelation therapy is needed?

Comment: Welcome Gary. I upvoted because it has the potential to be a fine question, but we are expected to show the results of our own investigations into a subject here, you can [edit] to tell us what your searches found and where the sticking points are. You should also take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance as to the ways of any site you post on.